# How do I loosely couple a process to a user interface for VBA and/or .Net?

Tags: .net, vb.net, vba, user-interface, loose-coupling

This question came to mind when I asked to put a progress bar on a long running process where the process has no concept of a user interface.  In fact, the process is being written into a library to be pulled in from other applications.  However, how do I provide a way for a WinForm to subscribe to the process to update as the process gets executed?  I've open this question from both VBA/VB6 and .Net because its part of the gamut for UI development.  It's also worth mentioning that these are subroutines and not classes that are running the methods, so event raising appears to be out of the question.  Should I expose incrementing variables as public?  Thanks in advance.

```
Adam:    Should we be eating of forbidden fruit?

Eve:     Yes.  I think so.  Go ahead Adam.

Serpant: Stop with the chit-chat and expose those variables already....

God:     Noooooooooooo!!!
```

Comment: Dear god, Have you considered service buses or XMPP?

Comment: @kenny Definately not out of the question to use as service.  But currently prototyping, so then it becomes a question of cost/benefit for this phase of the project, where benefits lose in this case.

Comment: What do you mean that these are subroutines and not classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's now need to expose your variables. How about writing a `ProcessCompletionStatus` subroutine which looks at those incrementing variables and tells how much has been done?

Comment: Do you mean on the form side or the module side?

Comment: On the side where those variables you mentioned live, which I interpreted to be the module side. The subroutine I'm talking about is meant to encapsulate the variables and provide the necessary information to the GUI at the same time

Comment: Your assumptions are correct.  Simple, yet genius.  Thank you sir.